# Put readonly for asp.net textbox if AutoPostBack="false"

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, readonly

I need to check if a TextBox has value then make that field readonly. I am using `AutoPostBack="false"` so no way I guess to do it on the backend.

Here is my code:

Aspx page:

```
<telerik:RadButton runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="btnLookup topIngbtnLookup" ID="btnIngredientsLookUp" Image-ImageUrl="~/Images/searchIng.PNG" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#txtIngredientsName').keypress(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $(this).addClass('readOnlyFields');
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('readOnlyFields');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.readOnlyFields {
    pointer-events: none !important;
    background-color: #ccc !important;
}
```

Comment: The control is a textbox or button?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `enabled` property.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%=btnIngredientsLookUp.ClientID %>').keypress(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            $(this).addClass('readOnlyFields');
            $(this).attr('enabled', 'false');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('readOnlyFields');
            $(this).attr('enabled', 'true');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks VDWWD I just tried this but didn't work for some reason!

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtIngredientsName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control TextCtrlReqNoSize input-HAMM20"></asp:TextBox> the problem if I add class readOnlyFields it will be be default readonly field